# Show that if f is a Lipschitz function $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} = 0 \forall n > 1 $

Tags: limits, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to show that if $f$ is a Lipschitz function then $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} = 0 \forall n > 1 $.

So far I proved that if $f$ is a Lipschitz function $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} \leq 0 \forall n > 1 $:

$f$ is Lipschitz so $\exists C \in \mathbb{R}: |f(x) - f(a)| \leq |x-a| \implies f(x) -f(a) \leq C|x| + C|a| \implies f(x) \leq C|x|+cte $.

Taking the limit, I have $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \leq \lim_{x \to +\infty} C|x| \implies \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} \leq \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{C|x|}{x^n} = 0 \forall n > 1$.

I don't know how to prove the other inequality. Any hint is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Take $g(x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: A few observations: you are using only half of Lipschitz condition, which actually allows you to conclude that $\lim sup f(x)/x^n\le 0$. If you use the other half you conclude that $\lim inf f(x)/x^n\ge 0$. Subhajit Ghosh's comment also works, but your conclusion is about $\lim sup$ in any case (then $\lim sup (-f(x)/x^n)=-\lim inf f(x)/x^n$). One more thing: you cannot take the limit before you divide by $x^n$.

Comment: Thanks @GReyes for your comments, please let me know if this is correct: $f(x)-f(a) \geq -C|x-a| \geq -C(|x| -|a|) = -C|x| + cte$.
Also, can you explain why is not correct to take the limit before I divide by $x^n$? Newbe here! Thanks